# How to develop a loop to scan array for consecutive values

Tags: python, arrays, logic

I'm developing an algorithm that scans a lat/lon box looking for particular shapes using Python. These shapes are created by looking for particular atmospheric conditions. For an array of latitude points to pass the algorithm test, I require the difference between one latitude point and the proceeding latitude point to be less than 1 degree (continuity requirement) and the difference between the minimum value and maximum value to be greater than 20 degrees (length requirement). The code listed below already does this.

```
if not (y_idx[:-1] - y_idx[1:] > 1).any(): 
# checks the difference between successor/predecessor latitudes at the array level (no loop)
      if y_idx.max() - y_idx.min() > 20
```

The bug I found is when I encounter an array that contains a segment of values that satisfies both the continuity and length requirements, but has outliers that cause the whole array to fail the continuity requirement and thus undesirably fail the test like this array below. My question is, how do I write a loop that continues if there is a segment that meets my requirements (like from -49.5/-73.5) while ignoring the outliers (like from -45/-46.5)?

I made in bold the discontinuity in the array

```
y_idx = [-45. -45.75 -46.5  -49.5  -49.5  -49.5  -50.25 -50.25 -50.25 -50.25 -50.25 -50.25 -50.25 -50.25 -50.25]
```

I tried creating new arrays for each batch of consecutive values and then testing those for the length, but I can't figure out the Python code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Numpy.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), calculate the difference along the array.Then, split the array [where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) the difference is lower than -1. Finally, get the longest array in produced arrays:

```
import numpy as np

y_idx = [-45., -45.75, -46.5, -49.5, -49.5, -49.5, -50.25, -50.25, -50.25, -50.25, -50.25, -50.25, -50.25, -50.25, -50.25]
x_idx = np.random.rand(len(y_idx))  # dummy data

indexes = np.where(np.diff(y_idx) < -1)[0] + 1
y_longest = max(np.split(y_idx, indexes), key=len)
x_longest = max(np.split(x_idx, indexes), key=len)
```

results:

```
y_longest = [-49.5  -49.5  -49.5  -50.25 -50.25 -50.25 -50.25 -50.25 -50.25 -50.25 -50.25 -50.25]
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant. I tested the code and it works as advertised. Thank you for the help. I do have one other question. There is a corresponding array of longitudes that is the same size as y_idx that is called x_idx. How would you split the x_idx along the same indices and choose the array that corresponds to "longest"?